# Script for an Add Button

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm need help with a script for a button that will add data input from specific cells (C2:E2) to a list that is on cells G:I(Same Spreadsheet). I created the button, but I am still learning coding, so I am having issues getting the button to work. 
[Here is what my spreadsheet looks like:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iIVvi.jpg)

I want what the user inputs for cells C2, D2 and E2 to be added to the right side at G-I when they click "ADD".

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you add this script, then add the script function named "concat" to the button it should work.

```js
function concat() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var ss1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var sourceRangeName = 'Sheet1!C2:E2'; // enter source range with sheet name included 
  var destRangeName = 'Sheet1!G:G'; 
  var fullNames = [];
  var names = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRange(sourceRangeName).getValues(); // names 
  
  // Sets users names
  for (var i = 0; i < names.length; i++) { 
    fullNames.push([names[i][0] + ' ' + names[i][1] + ' ' + names[i][2]]);
  }
   
  var destRange = ss.getRange(destRangeName).offset(0, 0, fullNames.length); 
   destRange.setValues(fullNames);
}
```

Comment: After applying it, and testing it, I see that it will over write the previous data, I need it to add it to the next possible line. Also, I dont know if its possible, but each of the cells need to go into their own. so for example: C2 > G1, D2 > H1, E2 > I1, and then next input will go on the next row.